# Computing a contour integral using the residue formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin z}{z^2}dz.$$

For some reason, my approach is giving me something similar but not the same as what Mathematica says I should get. My idea is to use the identity $\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$, split up the integral accordingly, and use separate semicircle contours for each (toward infinity for the left, toward negative infinity for the right). I took the difference of the residue formulas beforehand (anticipating that the integrals over the arcs would vanish), and it's not giving the right answer. Is there a problem with my approach? If not, I would like to know how to do it this way.

Comment: Do you really mean to have $z^4$ as the leading term in the denominator, or should it be $z^2$ ? Or maybe the $-4z$ term should be $-4z^2$? Either of these makes it much easier to find the poles of the integrand ;)

Comment: @MPW Yes, z^2, oops!

Comment: @MPW Just a typo. I've been working with the correct integral.

Comment: You probably just made a typo somewhere. The method seems correct but without further details of how exactly you split up the integral and calculated them both separately, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f(z) = \frac{ze^{3iz}}{z^{4} - 4z + 5}$.  Consider the integral
$$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{ze^{3iz}}{z^{2} - 4z + 5} \ dz$$
where $\gamma$ is a semi-circular contour with an anticlockwise orientation and radius $R$. With $R$ sufficiently large, $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z = 2+i$. By the Residue Theorem,
$$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{ze^{3iz}}{z^{2} - 4z + 5} \ dz = 2\pi i\lim_{z\to 2+i}(z - 2 - i)f(z) =  2\pi i\left(\frac{1}{2} - i\right)e^{-3+6i}$$
We then have that
$$\int_{-R}^{R}f(z) \ dz + \int_{\gamma'}f(z) \ dz = 2\pi i\left(\frac{1}{2} - i\right)e^{-3+6i}$$
where $\gamma'$ is the arc of the semi-circular contour. By Jordan's Lemma,
$$\left|\int_{\gamma'}f(z) \ dz \right| \leq \frac{\pi}{3}\max_{z \in [0,\pi]}\left\lbrace\left|\frac{Re^{iz}}{R^{2}e^{2iz} - 4Re^{iz} + 5}\right|\right\rbrace \leq \frac{\pi}{3}\frac{R}{R^{2}-4R-5}$$
Thus, as $R \to \infty$,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z) = 2\pi i\left(\frac{1}{2} - i\right)e^{-3+6i}$$
We look at the imaginary part to find that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{z\sin{3z}}{z^{2} - 4z + 5} \ dz = \frac{2\pi\sin{6}}{e^{3}} + \frac{\pi\cos{6}}{e^{3}}$$

Comment: Thanks! This seems different from my approach. Would my approach have worked?

Comment: It's hard to know without knowing exactly what you had done

Comment: Well my rough idea is in the description. Split into two integrals and use separate semicircles

Comment: I feel like it would have worked, but I haven't done it so it may surprise me. I would just stick to doing it like this.

Comment: Can you explain why we only look at the imaginary part at the end?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ze^{3iz}}{z^{2} - 4z + 5} \ dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{z\cos{3z}}{z^{2} - 4z + 5} \ dz + i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{z\sin{3z}}{z^{2} - 4z + 5} \ dz$

Comment: Circling back about this. Is there a way to do this without Jordan's lemma? I don't think I'm allowed to use that.